# XSLT 2.0: Check if string exists more than once in extern xml-file

Tags: xml, xslt

I am using an XSL-Stylesheet to transform 2 XML-Files in one.
first: Main.xml
second: SST.xml

I apply the stylesheet on the main.xml and want to check if a certain string is available in the second one. 
I am using

```
<xsl:when test="contains(document('SST.xml')/doors/module,$SignalName)">
```

where the variable SignalName includes the string I want to search for. This works fine! 
But now I want also to check, if this string exists only ONCE in the SST-file. If it exists more than once, it should stop the transformation and print an error like: "SignalName exists more than once in SST.xml" otherwise the transformations goes on normally. 
Somebody can tell my how to do it?

Edit: 
There is only one module node in the SST.xml but the SignalName is stored in the doors/module/object/Object___Text Node. There are several object nodes.
The invalid SignalNames are stored also in the doors/module/object/Object___Text nodes.

I added the idea of Martin Honnen to my code:

```
                    <xsl:choose>
                       <xsl:when test="contains(document('SST.xml')/doors/module,$SignalName)">  <!--Check if SST contains SignalName -->
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="(document('SST.xml')/doors/module/object/Object___Text[contains(., $SignalName)])[2]"> <!-- Check if it contains SignalName more than once -->
                                <xsl:message terminate="yes" select="$SignalName"> exists more than once in SST.xml</xsl:message><!-- Abort and throw an error -->
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise> <!-- Get Signal attributes -->
                                <L-4 L="EN"> 
                                    <TT><xsl:value-of select="concat('Signal_Type: ',document('SST.xml')/doors/module/object[Object___Text = $SignalName]/Signal_Type)"/></TT>
                                    <TT><xsl:value-of select="concat('Signal_Min: ',document('SST.xml')/doors/module/object[Object___Text = $SignalName]/Signal_Min)"/></TT>
                                    <TT><xsl:value-of select="concat('Signal_Max: ',document('SST.xml')/doors/module/object[Object___Text = $SignalName]/Signal_Max)"/></TT>
                                    <TT><xsl:value-of select="concat('Signal_Offset: ',document('SST.xml')/doors/module/object[Object___Text = $SignalName]/Signal_Offset)"/></TT>
                                    <TT><xsl:value-of select="concat('Signal_Resolution: ',document('SST.xml')/doors/module/object[Object___Text = $SignalName]/Signal_Resolution)"/></TT>
                                    <TT><xsl:value-of select="concat('SignalClass: ',document('SST.xml')/doors/module/object[Object___Text = $SignalName]/preceding-sibling::object[object_type='heading' and object_level='1'][1]/Object___Heading)"/></TT>
                                </L-4>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                          </xsl:when>
                          <xsl:otherwise> <!-- Signal doesn't exist in SST -->
                          <L-4 L="EN">
                          <TT>Signal was not found in SST</TT> 
                          </L-4>
                      </xsl:otherwise>
                  </xsl:choose>
```

It seems to work like this. Please tell me if you see some possible problems.

Comment: would be good to see an example of these files in something like http://jsfiddle.net/offroadcode/cufar/

Comment: Can there be more than one /doors/module element? If so, contains() will fail. Do you really want contains(), or do you want "="? And the second (invalid) occurrence of the string, can it be anywhere, or only in a module element? Please try to phrase your questions more carefully.

Comment: I've added additional information to my Question. I hope it's now clear. I also added the note from Martin Honnen. It seems to work fine. Thank you guys anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check that there are at least two `module` elements containing that string then you can do e.g.

```
<xsl:if test="(document('SST.xml')/doors/module[contains(., $SignalName)])[2]">
  <xsl:message terminate="yes" select="'SignalName exists more than once in SST.xml'"/>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: it was not in module, but it was easy to adapt the right path. Can you also add how to show the Value of $SignalName in the output comment? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can construct a string of course with XPath and `concat`: `<xsl:message terminate="yes" select="concat($SignalName, ' exists more than once in SST.xml.')"/>`.